# How to correctly define and use global variables in the module in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Fortran, we know that we can in a module define a global variable (use the private property), so that we can use the subroutines in the module to set or change the values of that variable. See below,

```
module Mod
integer, parameter :: r8=selected_real_kind(15,9)
real(kind=r8), private, save :: var
contains
subroutine f(x)
real(kind=r8) :: x
var = 2.0_r8*x
end subroutine f
end
```

As we can see, we can call f(x) and set the var in the module to be 2x.

Now in Julia, it seems like below,

```
module Mod
global var
function f(x::Float64)
global var = 2.0*x
return nothing
end
```

1. I mean, in the function, if var is on the left hand side, do I have to specify the key word 'global' every time?
2. I also tried to give the global var a type, like

   global var::Float64

But it gives me an error

```
syntax: type declarations on global variables are not yet supported
```

It seems i can only do either just specify nothing, like just

```
global var
```

or give it a value while setting its type,

```
global var=0.0::Float64
```

Is there better to just give the global var a type before using it?

Comment: A function with a side-effect is considered poor program practice in the Fortran world.  Your Fortran code is invalid, because a function result variable must be set before the function returns.  Presumably, `r8` is set someplace, but is used undefined, here.  The integer `2` is exactly representable in floating point, so `var = 2 * x` is much clearly than the expression you wrote.  Finally, a variable declared in the specification portion of a module implicitly has the `save` attribute, so `real(kind=r8), private, save :: var` is needlessly verbose.

Comment: @steve r8 obviously defined somewhere, I just did not show here because it is not relevant, I added it if you insist. I use subroutine not function in Fortran. A subroutine does not have to return any value, it just does its job. Finally you did not give any suggestions on the Julia part.

Comment: Don't use julia, so can't offer a suggestion how how to write poor code in another language.

Comment: @steve From your words I have no clue you are capable of writing high performace Fortran code. Your comments is not very useful since you are just repeating obvious things. If you feel you are capable in Fortran, please show some of your github Fortran code or something, and I would like to learn from them if any. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use github.  I do however know a bit about Fortran.  For example, you refer to `var` as *a global variable (use the private property)*.  `var` is not a global.  The `private`  attribute restricts `var`'s visibility to the module's namespace.  Section 19.2 of the Fortran 2018 standards defines global identifiers, and variables are not included in list.

Comment: @steve I say var is global (private), is to say that var is global within the module. I am not saying var is public.

Comment: @steve By the way, it is about Julia, not Fortran. Perhaps you are not good at Fortran, but if you are interested in learning Fortran, welcome to the Fortran disclosure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to make what you want and to make it efficient:

```
julia> const x = Ref(0)
Base.RefValue{Int64}(0)

julia> function f(y)
           x[] = y
       end

f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x[]
0

julia> f(10)
10

julia> x[]
10

julia> f("10")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int64

julia> f(5.0)
5.0

julia> x[]
5
```

Comments:

1. I make `x` a `const` which makes sure that the compiler will know its type (so that it can optimize code)
2. I make `x` a `Ref` to allow mutability of its contents and to make it clear later in the `x[] = y` statement that `x[]` part refers to a global variable (as variable `x` is not defined in a local scope of `f`)
3. As you can see in the example I could not use `"10"` in the call of `f` as it does not have a matching type. Note though that I could use `5.0` (a float) as it can be converted to an integer.

Comment: Thank you! This is excellent! Just one thing, what does [] in x[] mean?

Comment: This is a point of the solution. `x[]` means that you are accessing the contents of the container `x` (which is a single element container called `Ref` in this case, so you do not have to pass an index like with arrays). Because you are accessing the container it must already exist so Julia will not try creating it. If you have written `x = ` then in local scope Julia tries to create a variable `x`. If you write `x[] =` the variable `x` must already exist as you are accessing its contents. And this is exactly what you asked for.